# GeoServer | How to hide some attributes on WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms

I want to hide some attributes on WMS, but also I need these attributes on REST API request. For example when I access the WMS publicly on Google Earth I want to restrict some attributes from client. So they can't see when click on layer in Google Earth. But when user is logged in to website and authorized by REST API, they will access to all attributes .

[image]

[image]

Comment: a quick fix could be to just set no style for records that have that particular property value.....Not quite sure I understand your question though as in your text you mention 'feature', but in your screen captures, you are pointing to attributes. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @nr_aus In summary; I don't want some attributes to appear in public WMS service. But someone accessing GeoServer with Rest API should be able to see all the attributes.

Comment: The GeoServer rest api is for administration not data access - please edit your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Do you mean to access the data via WFS making a REST call? If so, you will ultimately need to create two layers and expose only the fields you want to on layer basis (eg.: layer1_users, layer1_admin). There is no attribute security but layer security. "GeoServer allows access to be determined on a per-layer basis."

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are after, but If you only want users to be able to info the layer after login, you can set up your security to grant specific users access to wms.GetFeatureInfo. a link that might help: [Service Security](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/service.html)

Comment: @bloigge yes, now that's exactly what I thought :) your answer was very enlightening. This is exactly what I wanted. But now I have a problem. I have a web application with a Nodejs server. More than 10 data will be entered daily through this application. I can handle what data goes into two different layers in nodejs. its fine, but sometimes i will add data by QGis. But qGis connects directly to geoserver. I have no idea how to add the data entered from qGis to two layers at once. In addition, when data is entered over QGis, the attributes coming to the user layer should be limited.

Comment: If you stick to this approach (Andreas answer is way better using geofence). both layers would need to reference the same data source (e.g.: Postgres DB Table). In QGIS you need to import just the correct WFS as a layer (e.g.: layer_user).

Comment: @bloigge Thank you very much, I was looking for a solution to this all day :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoServer basic security cannot do what you ask.
The GeoFence plugin, on the other hand, can limit attribute visibility on a per-user basis.

See here:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/geofence-server/index.html

Comment: You saved me from a serious headache :))